# How to delete all the queues in RabbitMQ using AMQP-CPP library

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to delete all the queues present in `RabbitMQ` server using `AMQP-CPP` library.

I could not find any methods in `AMQP-CPP` library that gives the `list of queues / deletes all the queues` present (if we are not specifying the queue name).

Could you please let me know if there are any possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMQP protocol doesn't have a method to list resources in a broker.

With RabbitMQ, you can use the REST API provided by the management plugin:

- To list all queues accross all vhosts:

  ```
  GET /api/queues
  ```
- To delete a queue in a given vhost:

  ```
  DELETE /api/queues/$vhost/$name
  ```

  This step can be done using AMQP too.

See the [complete list of REST endpoints](https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/master/priv/www/api/index.html) for more information.